# bigVideo.js showing text on screen prior to loading video

Tags: javascript, video.js

On my page, I load `bigVideo.js` as I've done on several other pages in the past:

```
$(function() {
            var BV = new $.BigVideo();
            BV.init();
            BV.show(selectedBg,{ambient:true});
        });
```

but prior to the video fully loading, it's showing this text on screen.  It goes away after the video loads:

[image]

What is this and how do I stop it from showing up on screen?

Answer (score 1):

That's part of the player skin. Try making sure the CSS is loaded earlier.